# VBA Excel: I am confused about which operator to use. "Or" does not give right results and "And" too

Tags: excel, vba, operators

I want the row to turn yellow if the date in column AJ or AK is in 2 weeks time, and red if column AJ or AK is today

I am using VBA, and I first wrote the code for AJ and it worked perfectly. I then used the "Or" operator, and it does not show required result

```
Dim i As Long 'i is a counter for rows
Const StartRow As Byte = 6 'Number of start row
Dim LastRow As Long 'lastrow is the last row
Dim myValue As Long 'myValue refers to difference between dates(today and AJ)
LastRow = Range("A" & StartRow).End(xlDown).Row

For i = StartRow To LastRow
    myValue = Range("AJ" & i).Value - Range("AJ1").Value Or Range("AK" & i).Value - Range("AJ1").Value 'AJ1 has today's date
    Select Case myValue

    'if AJ or AK is less than 14(in 2 weeks), row should be yellow
    Case 1 To 14
       Excel.Range("A" & i, "AP" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 '6 is yellow

    'if AJ or AK is 0 (that is today), then row should be red
    Case 0
    Excel.Range("A" & i, "AP" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 '3 means red

    'if AJ or AK is passed, row should go back to no fill
    Case Is <= -1
    Excel.Range("A" & i, "AP" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 0 '0 is no fill
    End Select Next i
```

Would expect that the row turns yellow or red depending on the case

Comment: You can't do it like that as `myValue` will return a Boolean. You have to work out the two values and then check them.

Comment: Since both operands are numeric values, the [Or](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/or-operator) and [And](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/and-operator) operators will probably perform bitwise comparison and return a Long

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help a little bit:

```
For i = StartRow To LastRow Step 1
    'red if column AJ or AK is today
    If Range("AJ" & i).Value = Date Or Range("AK" & i).Value = Date Then
        'color red whatever you want
        Range("A" & i, "AP" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 '3 means red
    ElseIf Abs(Date - Range("AJ" & i).Value) <= 14 Or Abs(Date - Range("AK" & i).Value) <= 14 Then
        'color yellow whatever you want
        Range("A" & i, "AP" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 '6 is yellow
    End If
Next i
```

This code will loop as yours. First, it will check if date in columns AJ or AK is equal to today. IF true, it will color the row using red. IF not, then it will check the difference between today's date and date in column AJ and also difference between today's date and date in column AK. If any of both is equal or less than 14, it means that date is in 2 weeks time.

Please note:

1. I've used today's date as reference when calculating the difference, with the command `Date`. If you need to calculate the difference using a different date as reference, then change `Date` with the date you need to use as reference.
2. I've used `Abs` to return the difference as a positive value. That way it will check if the date is in two weeks time, **ahead and behind** today's date. I mean, it checks the *future* and the *past*. I did it that way because maybe the difference could be -13.  That means there is a difference of 13 days too, but the number is negative. Using `Case 1 To 14` you are ignoring those cases. I don't know how is your data, so adapt it as you need.
3. When checking the if's, if both cases are false, then it will do nothing, so the row color won't be changed at all.

Hope this throws some light.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was however able to write code for conditional formatting and it works perfectly.